# Issue in calling a python script with some libraries from C#

Tags: python, c#, .net, cmd

I have a python script test.py which consist of libraries like cv2, numpy etc.

Now I want to run this script from C# code is something like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        start.Arguments = "/c activate base&&python C:/path_to/test.py";
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
                {
                    string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                process.WaitForExit();
            }  
   }
```

On running the above program, it doesn't show any output but if I replace my script with simple print statements i.e.

```
print("testing")
print("done")
```

It simply prints the above output on cmd!

P.S. I don't want to use ironpython as it only supports python2. I simply want to execute through cmd process as I mentioned above

Update : Updated the C# program by adding the `StandardError`

Adding the part of python script too!

```
 from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import numpy as np
import argparse
from cv2 import cv2
import imutils
import pydicom

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, default='sample.jpg',
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-east", "--east", type=str, default="east_text_detection.pb", 
    help="path to input EAST text detector")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--min-confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability required to inspect a region")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=int, default=640,
    help="resized image width (should be multiple of 32)")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--height", type=int, default=960,
    help="resized image height (should be multiple of 32)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#load the input image and 
if True in [args["image"].endswith(ext) for ext in [".dcm"]]:
    ds = pydicom.read_file(args["image"])
    #print(ds.pixel_array.shape)    
    image_2d = ds.pixel_array.astype(float)
    image_2d_scaled = (np.maximum(image_2d,0) / image_2d.max()) * 255.0
    image_2d_scaled = np.uint8(image_2d_scaled)
    image=cv2.cvtColor(image_2d_scaled,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    #print(image.shape)
else:
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
# grab the image dimensions

orig = image.copy() #### This line giving the error
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
```

The above line gives the error as `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`

If I run the python script standalone, it gives me no error and return the favorable output.

Comment: You're not reading StandardError; if there was an error it seems like you wouldn't know it. What happens if you read both StandardError and StandardOutput?

Comment: @RandomDavis updated the question along with error produced by C# program

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any arguments to the Python script. It's failing on `orig = image.copy()` because `image = cv2.imread(args["image"])`. You have to pass the `image` argument when calling the script from C#.

Comment: By default it takes sample.jpg as an argument so do we need to explicitly add the parameter in C#?

Comment: @YashSoni gotcha, well then you should share the entire stacktrace including the line number so I don't have to guess as to which line is throwing the error

Comment: Got it, the problem was in the path only, I had to specify the entire path for the script, the image, as well as the east text detector in the start.Arguments parameter. Opposed to what I posted above.